# Why my while loop is not working properly?

Tags: r

I am supposed to solve Problem 25 from Projecteuler. Below is my code, I have no clue, why it is not working.
Can anyone help me?

```
n <- 0  
a <- 1 
b <- 1 
c <- 0 
while (nchar(a)<1000)  
  n <- n+1  
  c <- b 
  b <- a 
  a <- a + c
```

Thanks

Comment: Don't know what you are trying to do but shouldn't you be checking just `a` in `while` instead of `nchar(a)` ?

Comment: No, because my task is to find index of the first term in the Fibonacci sequence to contain 1000 digits

Comment: Please add details of the problem to help add more context to the code.

Comment: Try using `while (a < 1000)` as Ronak suggested and wrap your `while` code within curly brackets

Comment: Okay, so for instance the 12the term in Fibonacci sequence is the first which contains three digits and I am supposed to find the first term in Fibonacci sequence which contains 1000 digits @NelsonGon

Comment: If i only use while (a < 1000), it will find me the gist them which is greater then 1000, but I want the term which contains 1000 digits @PoGibas

Answer (score 1):

This works for me. For 1000 digits, you will have to play the waiting game.

```
n <- 0  
a <- 1 
b <- 1 
c <- 0 
while (nchar(a) < 20) {
  n <- n+1  
  c <- b 
  b <- a 
  a <- a + c
}

> a
[1] 1.220016e+19
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to include `{...}` to your while

```
while (condition){
  ...some code....
} #
```